# ACF - updating field name and key

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm facing a big refactor job at one of my clients. Currently, we have a regular occurrence of more than 3 fields with different field name/key that contains the same information. We only want 1 field that we can include trou the GUI, the reasoning for doing this is to make our code more flexible and easier to implement.

I was messing around with refactoring field groups and fields within Atom and the SQL file today. This wasn't particularly successful as WordPress basically refused me admin access. (I was an admin in the database)

So my question is: Has anyone some experience doing this kind of "refactoring"? A plugin or script would be much appreciated as i really don't want to refactor 365 fields doing update_field("key","location") in Atom and a search/replace.

Comment: You have several different keys, all with the same value, and you want to deleted them except one? <- this is kinda straight forward to do

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just loop though all posts/pages/cpts and do the

```
update_field("key","location")
```

in the loop?

Comment: That's fine for the database, but it isn't really any good for the refactoring of our files

Comment: By files you mean your template files? How many files need to be updated?

Comment: > 100 files, thats alott  :/